# Saving CSV files in Foundry Transforms

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Is it possible to save a CSV file in Foundry Code Repositories transforms-python language rather than saving them in the Parquet format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by specifying the output dataset format when calling the `write_dataset` function. You can include compression options as well when making the call. For example:

```py
@transform(
    my_input = Input('/path/to/input/dataset'),
    my_output = Output('/path/to/output/dataset')
)
def compute_function(my_input, my_output):
    my_output.write_dataframe(
        my_input.dataframe(),
        output_format = "csv",
        options = {
            "compression": "gzip"
        }
    )
```

Comment: According to docstring this only holds writing a single input sPD to a single output. Any guess on outputting different? @Raj